# Every Riemann integrable function is almost equal to a bounded Lebesgue integrable function.

Tags: measure-theory

Let  $f  : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a Riemann integrable function. Then is it true that there always exists a bounded Lebesgue integrable function  $g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ and $f$  are almost equal but $g$ is not Riemann integrable. If it is true than how to prove and if it is false then can we find a counterexample.

I know that the zero function is almost equal to the Dirichlet function which is not Riemann integrable but is Lebesgue integrable. Thus the question that comes to my mind is that is it true for any Riemann integrable function.
.

Comment: Can you think of one Riemann integrable function having such a property?

Answer (score 2):

**This is true**

As $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, it is bounded on this interval. Take $c =2M$ where $M>0$ is a bound of $f$ and define

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & x \in [a,b] \setminus \mathbb Q\\
c & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$f$ and $g$ almost agree as they only differ on the countable set $[a,b]\cap \mathbb Q$. Therefore $g$ is also Lebesgue integrable.

However, $g$ is not Riemann integrable as it is nowhere continuous on $[a,b]$. And a map whose set of discontinuity points is having a strictly positive Lebesgue measure is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Discontinuous functions can be Riemann integrable.  I think the last part of your answer needs work.  I think it is true, but not for the reason you state.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith By discontinuous, I mean discontinuous at all points of $[a,b]$. A function whose set of discontinuity points has a strictly positive Lebesgue measure is not Riemann integrable. Hence $g$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Following your comment, I have an English wording question. What means *$f$ is discontinuous on $[a,b]$* in English? That it is not continuous on $[a,b]$ or that it is discontinuous at all points of $[a,b]$?

Comment: I would have thought the former.  But I guess it is ambiguous.  Best to be explicit as in your edited answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for improving myEnglish!